# kinetic : rviz segfaults when loading panel

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i use ubuntu 16.04 and kinetic kame, when i run   rosrun rviz rviz  all runs well, but when i try to load a rviz plugin which adds a panel, it crashes and tells  segmention fault  ?

i changed CMakeListst.txt to support Qt5 , here the CMakeListst.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(flobotics_finger_rviz_controller)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rviz
  flobotics_finger_messages
)

## This plugin includes Qt widgets, so we must include Qt.
## We'll use the version that rviz used so they are compatible.
if(rviz_QT_VERSION VERSION_LESS "5")
  message(STATUS "Using Qt4 based on the rviz_QT_VERSION: ${rviz_QT_VERSION}")
  find_package(Qt4 ${rviz_QT_VERSION} EXACT REQUIRED QtCore QtGui)
  ## pull in all required include dirs, define QT_LIBRARIES, etc.
  include(${QT_USE_FILE})
else()
  message(STATUS "Using Qt5 based on the rviz_QT_VERSION: ${rviz_QT_VERSION}")
  find_package(Qt5 ${rviz_QT_VERSION} EXACT REQUIRED Core Widgets)
  ## make target_link_libraries(${QT_LIBRARIES}) pull in all required dependencies
  set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)
endif()

add_definitions(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)



###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  include/flobotics_finger_rviz_controller/
  include/flobotics_finger_rviz_servo_controller/
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

 
set(SRC_FILES
  src/flobotics_finger_rviz_controller.cpp
  src/flobotics_finger_rviz_servo_controller.cpp
 )

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES}) 

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
 target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
   ${QT_LIBRARIES}
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )
```

when i then run catkin_make, it tells me:
`-- Using Qt5 based on the rviz_QT_VERSION: 5.5.1`
but then errors following, like:

```
In file included from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/flobotics_finger_rviz_controller/src/flobotics_finger_rviz_servo_controller.cpp:3:0:
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/flobotics_finger_rviz_controller/include/flobotics_finger_rviz_servo_controller/flobotics_finger_rviz_servo_controller.h:18:1: error: ‘signals’ does not name a type
 signals:
 ^
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/flobotics_finger_rviz_controller/include/flobotics_finger_rviz_servo_controller/flobotics_finger_rviz_servo_controller.h:22:5: error: ‘QVBoxLayout’ does not name a type
     QVBoxLayout* _vbox;
     ^
```

I tried to include  #include  but nothing changed

i think it has something todo with the qt5 install on ubuntu 16.04 ? if i look at /usr/include/ there is only a qt4 dir,  in /usr/share/ is a qt5 directory.

> i run qtchooser -qt=qt5

but nothing changed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233795/kinetic-:-rviz-segfaults-when-loading-panel/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2016-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't enough information to help you (it could segfault for many reasons). If you want to provide more information edit your question (don't post a new answer) please.

A theory as to why it crashes is that rviz uses Qt5 in Kinetic. I don't know what you mean by "panel", but I assume you mean a custom rviz plugin which adds a panel. Make sure your plugin is use Qt5 as well, otherwise it can crash (due to mixing Qt4 and Qt5 runtimes).

For an example of how to make this change to a plugin see:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/compare/indigo-devel...kinetic-devel#diff-6bfff24e6e5ebb7d838a40ca33f65e0a

This is the file as-is for Kinetic:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/rviz_plugin_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2016-07-06**:
I ran into the exact same problem and your explanation and provided links worked perfectly. I just upvoted your answer, thanks a bunch William!

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2016-11-30**:
Very useful information, the example CMakeLists is very detailed, great job :)

**Comment by [nmerrill67](https://answers.ros.org/users/30786/nmerrill67/) on 2017-06-15**:
I have been trying to fix this problem for months. Thank you!